# Unable to find radio button element using checked="Checked" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, geb

I used `div.find("input","checked":contains("checked"))` in geb.

Here is the actual code snippet I used to identify the checked radio button of a web page, but it is giving an error on `"input","checked":contains("checked")`

```
seletedRadio(wait:true,required:false){
  $("tbody.option-group-container")
  .getAt(0)
  .find("input","checked":contains("checked"))
  .next("label")
  .find("span.label-text")
}
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: unable to find the element.

Comment: Whu  u are not using isSelected or not

Comment: Did you check that the checkbox html is definitely being updated to have checked="checked" once you select it manually.  Posting some html and the error received would certainly be useful.

Comment: <input checked="checked" =""="" type="radio" id="NB_APU_MB" name="NB_CPU" label="Processor,2.3GHz"> here is the html that i am trying to inspect

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax for checkbox:

```
find("input:checkbox:checked")
```

and this for radios:

```
find("input:radio:checked")
```

(also it seems a typos in **seletedRadio** word.)

Comment: it is not a checkbox, it is a radio button. Thanks

Comment: OK. Please check the answer again

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.waiting.UnknownWaitForEvaluationResult.text() is applicable for argument types: () tried this solution, and getting this error message

Comment: I guess that you want to consume the value of object but you are consuming the object itself ! So just add `.val()` to get the value of checked object or add `.html()` after span to get the inner html of that span.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you could use selector `input[name=value]:checked` to get selected value. check below example

```js
console.log($('input[name=gender]:checked').val());
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<label for=""><input type="radio" name = 'gender' value = 'M' > Male</label>
<label for=""><input type="radio" name = 'gender' value = 'F' checked> Female</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this xpath and try

```
//input[@type='radio'][@checked='']
```

Comment: That's not very helpful without saying how you use xpath in JS.

Answer (score 0):

[Geb has a module for working with radio buttons.](http://gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/module/RadioButtons.html) So if your radio buttons were something like:

```
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="radio" value="option1">
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="radio" value="option2">
```

You could have a selector like:

```
radioMod {$("input", name: "radio").module(RadioButtons)}
```

And use getChecked to return the value:

```
radioMod.getChecked()
```